# Directive that replaces content not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive that should replace a number with a string but it keeps showing the number.

```
// CS compiled
app.directive('stock', [
  '$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function(scope, element) {
        var display, html;
        html = $interpolate(element.html())(scope);
        display = (function() {
          switch (html) {
            case '0':
              return 'Out of stock';
            case '1':
              return 'Available';
            case '2':
              return 'Available 3-5 days';
            case '3':
              return 'Available 2 weeks';
            case '4':
              return 'Available 2 months';
            default:
              return '';
          }
        })();
        return element.html(display);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

When debugging I see the content is being replaced.

[image]

[image]

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PDykq/1/)

Comment: What error did you see? I just tried and there was no error at all. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PDykq/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PDykq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to pass 0 as a string. And you should use scope and get the status, that will be easier. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PDykq/2/).

tpl:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <label class="stock" status="status"></label>
</div>
```

js:

```
// CS compiled
app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.status = '0'; //pass as string since you filter on string in the case statement
})
app.directive('stock', [
    '$interpolate', function ($interpolate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: {
            status: '=status'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var display, html;
            html = $interpolate(element.html())(scope);
            display = (function () {
                switch (scope.status) {
                    case '0':
                        return 'Out of stock';
                    case '1':
                        return 'Available';
                    case '2':
                        return 'Available 3-5 days';
                    case '3':
                        return 'Available 2 weeks';
                    case '4':
                        return 'Available 2 months';
                    default:
                        return '';
                }
            })();
            return element.html(display);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `{{...}}` in your element, so angular is in charge of update the element's content, your manual changes to innerHTML are effectively overwritten by the framework. Also, your implementation is to use HTML text as the medium to share data, which isn't the angular way for dealing with data.

sza's answer has nailed the problem, it works perfectly; however, from your question I see that you don't want to create new scope for this directive, then the directive's scope is `$rootScope`, you have full access to the `status` by simply using `scope.status` in your link function.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <label class="stock"></label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('stock', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var display = (function () {
                switch (scope.status) {
                    case 0:
                        return 'Out of stock';
                    case 1:
                        return 'Available';
                    case 2:
                        return 'Available 3-5 days';
                    case 3:
                        return 'Available 2 weeks';
                    case 4:
                        return 'Available 2 months';
                    default:
                        return '';
                }
            })();
            element.html(display);
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Vyz9/1/

### Furthermore

If you want the label updates itself whenever the `status` changes, you can use `$watch` in the linking function.

JS:

```
app.directive('stock', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('status', function () {
                var display = (function () {
                    switch (scope.status) {
                        case 0:
                            return 'Out of stock';
                        case 1:
                            return 'Available';
                        case 2:
                            return 'Available 3-5 days';
                        case 3:
                            return 'Available 2 weeks';
                        case 4:
                            return 'Available 2 months';
                        default:
                            return '';
                    }
                })();
                element.html(display);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Vyz9/2/